# Getting mobile data usage history using NetworkStatsManager

Tags: android, permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow, networkstatsmanager

I want to know the data usage history and noticed the "new" android-6 [`NetworkStatsManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/NetworkStatsManager.html) which seems positive (I've used `TrafficStats` a while but that won't cover anything previous a reboot).

From the API documentation:

> NOTE: This API requires the permission PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS, which is a
>   system-level permission and will not be granted to third-party apps.
>   However, declaring the permission implies intention to use the API and
>   the user of the device can grant permission through the Settings
>   application. Profile owner apps are automatically granted permission
>   to query data on the profile they manage (that is, for any query
>   except querySummaryForDevice(int, String, long, long)). Device owner
>   apps likewise get access to usage data of the primary user.

I want to know the data usage on a aggregated level and *not* down to which app that uses the data so I tried to use it like this:

```
NetworkStatsManager service = context.getSystemService(NetworkStatsManager.class);

NetworkStats.Bucket bucket = 
        service.querySummaryForDevice(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE, null, from, to);
...
```

Unfortunately that throws a `SecurityException`:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: NetworkStats: Neither user 10174 nor current process has android.permission.READ_NETWORK_USAGE_HISTORY.
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1620)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1573)
at android.net.INetworkStatsSession$Stub$Proxy.getDeviceSummaryForNetwork(INetworkStatsSession.java:259)
at android.app.usage.NetworkStats.getDeviceSummaryForNetwork(NetworkStats.java:316)
at android.app.usage.NetworkStatsManager.querySummaryForDevice(NetworkStatsManager.java:100)
...
```

The `android.permission.READ_NETWORK_USAGE_HISTORY` permission is not allowed for third party apps. So this seemed like a dead end.

However, I drilled down a bit into the internals and found out that you can use the internal/hidden API to do the same thing without requesting any permissions:

```
INetworkStatsService service =
        INetworkStatsService.Stub.asInterface(
                ServiceManager.getService(Context.NETWORK_STATS_SERVICE));

INetworkStatsSession session = service.openSession();

NetworkTemplate mobileTemplate = NetworkTemplate.buildTemplateMobileWildcard();
int fields = NetworkStatsHistory.FIELD_RX_BYTES | NetworkStatsHistory.FIELD_TX_BYTES;

NetworkStatsHistory mobileHistory = session.getHistoryForNetwork(mobileTemplate, fields);

for (int i = 0; i < mobileHistory.size(); i++) {
    NetworkStatsHistory.Entry entry = mobileHistory.getValues(i, null);
    ...
}

session.close();
```

I really want to do the same with the public API, so, how do I do just that?

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to do the same thing. For this permission: android.permission.READ_NETWORK_USAGE_HISTORY I remove warning on manifest and the app finally installed on my device. But when I try to get TYPE_MOBILE it return always 0. WIFI works fine. Have you resolved this issue? please let me know :)

Comment: i also getting always 0

Comment: @aj0822ArpitJoshi Have you been able to fix this? I am having same issue with mobile data in android 8 devices (not all devices, but some)

Comment: Second parameter of `querySummaryForDevice` shouldn't be null; use `telephonyManager.getSubscriberId()` instead

Answer (score 23):

There is way to obtain the access to `NetworkStateManager` without getting access to private API. Here are the steps:

1. Declare the required permissions in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

   ```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
   <uses-permission
       android:name="android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS"
       tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions"/>
   ```

   2. Ask for permission in `Activity`

   `android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS` is not a normal permission, there cannot be simply requested. In order to check, whether the permission has been granted, check:

   ```
   AppOpsManager appOps = (AppOpsManager) getSystemService(Context.APP_OPS_SERVICE);
   int mode = appOps.checkOpNoThrow(AppOpsManager.OPSTR_GET_USAGE_STATS,
           android.os.Process.myUid(), getPackageName());
   if (mode == AppOpsManager.MODE_ALLOWED) {
       return true;
   }
   ```

   To ask for this permission, simply call `Intent`:

   ```
   Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS);
   startActivity(intent);
   ```

   Another permmission is also needed: `Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE`. It is needed only, when you need to get [mobile data statistics](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/8ba9340/tests/tests/app.usage/src/android/app/usage/cts/NetworkUsageStatsTest.java#405). However, this is normal permission so can be [requested as any other permission](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

   3. Use `NetworkStatsManager`:

Made a sample [Github repo](https://github.com/RobertZagorski/NetworkStats) demonstrating the usage.

Comment: I'm stuck with READ_NETWORK_USAGE_HISTORY. tried out the repo on a 6.0.1 and got strange number from the NetworkStatsManager side. Are you sure this hack is still working? thanks a ton!

Comment: getSubscriberId() is unfortunately crashing with java.lang.SecurityException: getSubscriberId: The user 10435 does not meet the requirements to access device identifiers in Android 11

Answer (score 1):

```
/*
getting youtube usage for both mobile and wifi.
 */
public long getYoutubeTotalusage(Context context) {
    String subId = getSubscriberId(context, ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
    return getYoutubeUsage(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE, subId) + getYoutubeUsage(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI, "");
}


private long getYoutubeUsage(int networkType, String subScriberId) {
    NetworkStats networkStatsByApp;
    long currentYoutubeUsage = 0L;
    try {
        networkStatsByApp = networkStatsManager.querySummary(networkType, subScriberId, 0, System.currentTimeMillis());
        do {
            NetworkStats.Bucket bucket = new NetworkStats.Bucket();
            networkStatsByApp.getNextBucket(bucket);
            if (bucket.getUid() == packageUid) {
                //rajeesh : in some devices this is immediately looping twice and the second iteration is returning correct value. So result returning is moved to the end.
                currentYoutubeUsage = (bucket.getRxBytes() + bucket.getTxBytes());
            }
        } while (networkStatsByApp.hasNextBucket());

    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return currentYoutubeUsage;
}


private String getSubscriberId(Context context, int networkType) {
    if (ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE == networkType) {
        TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        return tm.getSubscriberId();
    }
    return "";
}
```