# Getting deepest details of Android Data Usage history

Tags: android, linux, network-programming

### I need to get Data Usage history of Android device.

**Which of these features can I have ? and how ?**

```
1-Daily data usage or even hourly.

2-From the last device data wipe date to now.

3-Contains application details.
```

## **Attention**

```
I don't want to monitor and save data usage history.

I want to have it all after installing the application.

**Please** tell if there is more than one way And also if thy need Root access 
Or if they work on a specific API version.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Back in old ages, I wanted to capture data usage of the device without monitoring it. The only method that I know back then was to capture every thing using a service in background and I thought that would be CPU heavy. ([TrafficStats](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/TrafficStats) was the only way to go back then)

To answer the question for others who might see it I should say the following.

- From API 23 there is a function called [NetworkStatsManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/NetworkStatsManager) that
  can do this. I should Also link to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39412172/1454173) and [his work on
  github](https://github.com/RobertZagorski/NetworkStats).
- According to google document you can get data usage for any period of time between Long.MIN_VALUE and Long.MAX_VALUE.

  > Queries can define a time interval in the form of start and end
  >   timestamps (Long.MIN_VALUE and Long.MAX_VALUE can be used to simulate
  >   open ended intervals).
- You can get usage of other applications classified based on their UID that you can then turn to package name and etc. ([Referral project](https://github.com/darryncampbell/Network-Stats-Logger))
- There are 5 ways of doing so as in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/NetworkStatsManager).

  > Summary queries
  >
  > querySummaryForDevice(int, String, long, long)
  >
  > querySummaryForUser(int, String, long, long)
  >
  > querySummary(int, String, long, long)
  >
  > These queries aggregate network usage across the whole interval.
  >   Therefore there will be only one bucket for a particular key, state,
  >   metered and roaming combination. In case of the user-wide and
  >   device-wide summaries a single bucket containing the totalised network
  >   usage is returned.
  >
  > History queries
  >
  > queryDetailsForUid(int, String, long, long, int)
  >
  > queryDetails(int, String, long, long)
  >
  > These queries do not aggregate over time but do aggregate over state,
  >   metered and roaming. Therefore there can be multiple buckets for a
  >   particular key. However, all Buckets will have state
  >   NetworkStats.Bucket.STATE_ALL, defaultNetwork
  >   NetworkStats.Bucket.DEFAULT_NETWORK_ALL, metered
  >   NetworkStats.Bucket.METERED_ALL, roaming
  >   NetworkStats.Bucket.ROAMING_ALL.